# Android shopping cart app remove item action

Tags: android, textview

I am developing an Android shopping cart app. In cart activity, If i add product, the total price is displayed automatically in text view at the bottom of the screen. My question is:  how to automatically change the total value to the decreased amount when removing a product from the cart list.

Comment: surprisingly, it all depends on your code, but in general - do the same as you do when adding - re-calculate it.

Comment: When you remove the item, find it's value / price and subtract from the total value, display the result in total value. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are removing an item, run a loop through the items to calculate the new total price. Or, you can calculate the total price of the removed items, and deduct that from the previous total.

Some sample code can get you more help.